# How to set up backbone and tastypie to properly send the api_key and username when doing a POST request

Tags: django, backbone.js, tastypie

When I do a request through curl, passing the username+ApiKey through the url like:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"question": "Is a test yo?", "pub_date": "2011-05-22T00:46:38"}' "http://localhost:8000/polls/api/v1/poll/?username=federico&api_key=10a2d3586e63078ef39f9da8f9aa9209715ed282
```

I have no problem (other than the server complaining it's a bad request because I'm not sending the FK data, but the db is updated anyways.

However when I try to do the same thing by sending the username+apikey **through the header**  I get a 401 Unauthorized error and nothing happens.

What am I missing here?

```
#resources

class PollResource(ModelResource):
    choices = fields.ToManyField('polls.api.ChoiceResource', 'choice_set', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Poll.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'poll'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()


class ChoiceResource(ModelResource):
    poll = fields.ForeignKey(PollResource, 'poll')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Choice.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'choice'
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']



// js

// backbone-tastypie config
Backbone.Tastypie.csrfToken = $("#secret-token")[0].value;
Backbone.Tastypie.apiKey = {
    username: USER,
    key: API_KEY
};

// model
var Poll = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/polls/api/v1/poll/'
});
```

Request from Backbone with ApiKey in HTTP_Authorization header:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/polls/api/v1/poll/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:401 UNAUTHORIZED
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:ApiKey federico:10a2d3586e63078ef39f9da8f9aa9209715ed282
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:109
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:djdt=hide; sessionid=96ca6e066bab30f241819b22cc85693b; csrftoken=PYMw9nrqh3TOqse3GM3ojU5iSOV2QMUA
Host:localhost:8000
Origin:http://localhost:8000
Referer:http://localhost:8000/index/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17
X-CSRFToken:PYMw9nrqh3TOqse3GM3ojU5iSOV2QMUA
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
{"csrfmiddlewaretoken":"PYMw9nrqh3TOqse3GM3ojU5iSOV2QMUA","question":"What is love?","pub_date":"07/02/2013"}
Response Headersview source
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 07 Feb 2013 21:57:01 GMT
Server:WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.1
Vary:Cookie
```

Edit: I've been trying to debug this and apparently it's some issue with the url...

This is my project's url.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^index/$', 'polls.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
)
```

and this is the app's url.py

```
v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')
v1_api.register(PollResource())
v1_api.register(ChoiceResource())

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
)
```

Comment: maybe you could dump the request from the browser, e.g. see network tab on Chrome dev tools?

Comment: the critical http header field probably is:  Authorization:ApiKey federico:10a2d3586e63078ef39f9da8f9aa9209715ed282  How are you sending this token with Backbone? Maybe you should send it with a jQuery header/credentials field too?

Comment: @poseid the request dump is under the Poll model. I'm sending it by using backbone-tastypie (https://github.com/PaulUithol/backbone-tastypie/blob/master/backbone_tastypie/static/js/backbone-tastypie.js). I wrote my config options in the question, and if you cehck backone-tastypie's source you can see what it's doing is overriding Backbone.sync for this.

Comment: can you check what you see on your server? (header authentication and signed request?)

Comment: that's being sent correctly according to the DevTools "Authorization:ApiKey federico:10a2d3586e63078ef39f9da8f9aa9209715ed282"

Comment: @poseid edited because I think it might have something to do with the url setup.

Comment: Is it an issue with mod_wsgi (or other webserver) capturing the Authorization field in the header and it not getting through to TastyPie? Sorry not sure what `DevTools` is, or where it is in the request cycle.